# Возврат массива из метода, как это работает?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
enum Suits
    {
        Wands,
        Coins,
        Cups,
        Swords
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Suits suit = Suits.Wands;

        string getSuits()
        {
            return new []{"0","1","2","3" }[(int)suit];
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(getSuits());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как именно работает возврат массива в коде выше, где можно почитать документацию по поводу этого возврата?

Comment: метод getSuits возвращает не массив а элемент из него (а именно "0", надеюсь ничего не перепутал) или в чем вопрос, не понял?

Comment: Вы хотите получить количество элементов в перечислении? Используйте `Enum.GetValues<T>`

Comment: @Frehzy тут даже намека на Count или Length или количество нет.

Comment: @aepot Да я посмотрел на количество элементов в перечислении и в массиве и предположил, что человек хочет получить что-то подобное, но не знает, как объяснить это